# undefined method `ljust' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby and recently completed an assignment to create a table of contents. The code works, however, at the end of the code, the following error occurs:

```
table_of_contents2.rb:23:in `<main>': undefined method `ljust' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I've double checked that the outline variable is not `nil` by doing a `puts outline` within the while loop, and tried changing the `outline` variable to `@outline` and `$outline` throughout the code, but the error has persisted.

The full code is below:

```
lineWidth = 40

chapters = ["Chapter 1: Numbers", "Chapter 2: Letters",
          "Chapter 3: Variables"]
pages = ["page 1","page 72","page 118"]

puts "Table of Contents".center lineWidth


outline = []

i = 0

while i < 3
  outline.push(chapters[i])
  outline.push(pages[i])
  i = i + 1
end

j = 0

while j <= outline.length
  puts outline[j].ljust(lineWidth/2) +
  outline[j+1].rjust(lineWidth/2)
  j = j + 2
end
```

Why is this error occurring? And why is it happening after the code has successfully run?

Addendum: I'm running the code in the Terminal. The full display within the terminal when I run the code is as follows:

```
$ ruby table_of_contents2.rb
           Table of Contents            
Chapter 1: Numbers                page 1
Chapter 2: Letters               page 72
Chapter 3: Variables            page 118
table_of_contents2.rb:23:in `<main>': undefined method `ljust' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programming languages start indexing at 0, but numeric values (like the length of an array) are just used normally.

So an array will return 5 items when asked how long it is (`.length`), but the largest index in the array is 4.

In your case, you get up until the last item in the array (`<=`) and then try to access an index that's one greater than exists (you're asking if the incrementor is smaller).

Change `<=` to `<` so it doesn't also do that when the incrementor is equal to the size of the array:

`while j < outline.length`

---

That's it.

0 indexing, real simple but very quickly gets confusing when thinking about how to iterate over data.

Ruby has some more convenient functions that abstract this for you. See `.each`:

```
collection.each do |i, element|
   puts i
   puts element
end
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is at the line `while j <= outline.length`.

It should be `while j < outline.length`.

However, in Ruby, manually maintaining a cursor is often considered a bad practice. Your program can be rewritten as

```
line_width = 40

chapters = ["Chapter 1: Numbers", "Chapter 2: Letters",
          "Chapter 3: Variables"]
pages = ["page 1","page 72","page 118"]

puts "Table of Contents".center line_width

chapters.zip(pages).each do |chapter, page|
  puts chapter.ljust(line_width/2) + page.rjust(line_width/2)
end
```

By the way, Ruby programmers prefer underscore to camelcase (except for class names and module names), so I changed `lineWidth` to `line_width`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access `outline[outline.length]` that's why it returns `nil`. ( Arrays indexes in Ruby are between `0` and `length - 1` )

Change this line :

```
 while j <= outline.length
```

by this one:

```
 while j < outline.length
```

Comment: You want either one of `<` or `outline.length - 1`, not both.

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks